# Append values to Access table from Excel with ID autogenerated

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

I have an Access database with some tables which get updated daily with some values. I need the tables to have an `ID` field which is auto-generated when the other values of the table are imported from Excel. I want to automate all by keeping a button and writing a VBA code. Right now I have a form which imports the value into the table, but it just imports the exact values which I have. I also need an extra column of `ID` that has to be auto generated when I import. Please help me.

Excel Sheet Sample:

```
ProductName | ProductValue
------------+--------------
ABC         | 76
SDF         | 87
```

DATABASE TABLE

```
ID|ProductName| Product Value
--+-----------+--------------
1 | ABC       |76
2 | SDF       |87
```

Excel sheet updates each day with new value and it has to be put to the Access database with `ID` automatically incremented. So after the daily update the values are incremented from the previous value.

```
Dim filepath As String

filepath = "E:\rt.xlsx"
If FileExist(filepath) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "TempfromExcel", filepath, True
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryAppend", acViewNormal

Else
    MsgBox ("File not found.")
End If
```

Comment: I have created temporary table which imports the value and have a written a append query to append the values.

Comment: Hope the question is clear. I want to generate ID auto number from the previous number in the table.

Comment: What updates? The product value in access? And you want that to update the excel sheet?

Comment: If you want to have a unique value column, you should add an `AutoNumber` field to your Access table, Then if you want to have a field that always return from 1 to row counts of your table you should create a `View` for that ;).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the best method is to set the `ID` field to be an `AutoNumber`. If you already have a bunch of data in that field, you will need to [reset the field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812718).

[image: Setting an AutoNumber]

Once that's done, simply don't include the field in your append query. Access will automatically fill in whatever the next value is for each new record.